# Eigenvalues and inverse of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be a $3$x$3$ matrix and suppose that 1, 2, 3 are the Eigenvalues of $M$.

If $$M^{-1}=\frac{M^2}{\alpha}-M+\frac{11}{\alpha}I$$

Where $I$ is the identity matrix of order 3. Given $\alpha\neq0$. Find the value of $\alpha$ ?

I am not sure how to proceed. Please help!

Edit: $+11/\alpha$ and not $-11/\alpha$

Comment: Hint: What’s the minimal polynomial of $M$ and what is its relationship to the given equation satisfied by $M$?

Comment: I presume you want $+11/\alpha$ not $-11/\alpha$.

Comment: And yeah i think it should be +11

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, it is $+11/\alpha$ , I rechecked with another source. There was a printing mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$\alpha I=M^3-\alpha M^2+11M.$$
The minimal polynomial of $M$ is $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$; this divides
any polynomial $f$ with $f(M)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of $A$ is
$$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=0$$

Then use Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Then you can easily find $A^{-1}$.

The answer is $6$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=M^{-1}M=\frac{M^3}{\alpha}-M^2-\frac{11}{a}M$$
thus
$$\frac{M^3}{\alpha}-M^2-\frac{11}{a}M-I=0$$
or
$$M^3-\alpha M^2-11M-\alpha I=0$$

By the Cayley Hamilton theorem, a matrix is a root of its characteristic polynomial, thus

$$M^3-\alpha M^2-11M-\alpha I=(M-3I)(M-2I)(M-I) $$

Now,

Which can be rewritten 
$$M^3-\alpha M^2-11M-\alpha I=M^3-6M^2+11M-6I$$

Which makes me think that the answer is $6$ and there's a typo in your question ($-11$ instead of $11$)

Answer (score 0):

Multiply whole equation by $M$ and apply $U^{-1}$ and $U$ (matrix to diagonalize $M$)to the resulting equation. Then you know what to do.